# How to grab keys and values of a json output and make new valid json with those?

Tags: command-line, bash, json

I can make an request to the sonarr api which will give me the following output:

```bsh
curl -sL "http://192.168.2.15:8005/api/series/lookup?term=tvdb:81189&apikey=[[REMOVED]]" | jq .[]
```

```json
{
  "title": "Breaking Bad",
  "sortTitle": "breaking bad",
  "seasonCount": 5,
  "status": "ended",
  "overview": "When Walter White, a chemistry teacher, is diagnosed with Stage III cancer and given a prognosis of two years left to live, he chooses to enter a dangerous world of drugs and crime with the intent to secure his family's financial security.",
  "network": "Netflix",
  "airTime": "21:00",
  "images": [
    {
      "coverType": "banner",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/81189-g21.jpg"
    },
    {
      "coverType": "poster",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/81189-10.jpg"
    },
    {
      "coverType": "fanart",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/81189-21.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "remotePoster": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/81189-10.jpg",
  "seasons": [
    {
      "seasonNumber": 0,
      "monitored": false
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 1,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 2,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 3,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 4,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 5,
      "monitored": true
    }
  ],
  "year": 2008,
  "profileId": 0,
  "languageProfileId": 0,
  "seasonFolder": false,
  "monitored": true,
  "useSceneNumbering": false,
  "runtime": 47,
  "tvdbId": 81189,
  "tvRageId": 18164,
  "tvMazeId": 169,
  "firstAired": "2008-01-20T00:00:00Z",
  "seriesType": "standard",
  "cleanTitle": "breakingbad",
  "imdbId": "tt0903747",
  "titleSlug": "breaking-bad",
  "certification": "TV-MA",
  "genres": [
    "Crime",
    "Drama",
    "Suspense",
    "Thriller"
  ],
  "tags": [],
  "added": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "ratings": {
    "votes": 31714,
    "value": 9.4
  },
  "qualityProfileId": 0
}
```

I want to grab keys and values out of that output and make a new valid json output with those.
These are the keys (+ values) that need to be in the new output:

1. `title`
2. `profileId`
3. `tvdbId`
4. `titleSlug`
5. `images` (and all its contents and children)
6. `seasons` (and all its contents and children)

For one key, the value needs to be changed. The new value is stored in a variable:

1. `profileId` (variable `$profile_id`)

A few things need to be added to the new output (that aren't in the output of the api):

1. `"rootFolderPath": ".....",` (value for key is stored in variable `$root_folder_path`)
2. 

```json
"addOptions":
{
  "ignoreEpisodesWithFiles": false,
  "ignoreEpisodesWithoutFiles": false,
  "searchForMissingEpisodes": false
}
```

The result (taking the example output above) should be the following:

```json
{
  "title": "Breaking Bad",
  "rootFolderPath": "/home/cas/plex-media/series",
  "profileId": 1,
  "tvdbId": 81189,
  "titleSlug": "breaking-bad",
  "images": [
    {
      "coverType": "banner",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/81189-g21.jpg"
    },
    {
      "coverType": "poster",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/81189-10.jpg"
    },
    {
      "coverType": "fanart",
      "url": "https://artworks.thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/81189-21.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "seasons": [
    {
      "seasonNumber": 0,
      "monitored": false
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 1,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 2,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 3,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 4,
      "monitored": true
    },
    {
      "seasonNumber": 5,
      "monitored": true
    }
  ],
  "addOptions":
  {
    "ignoreEpisodesWithFiles": false,
    "ignoreEpisodesWithoutFiles": false,
    "searchForMissingEpisodes": false
  }
}
```

I would strongly prefer this to work without saving to a file. So it can be a small piece of bash code or a one-liner/long pipe, as long as it doesn't involve saving to a file or something. Just doing all the stuff that needs to be done and safe the new output in a variable for example.

Comment: Have a look at `jq` command-line JSON processor. `sudo apt  install jq` `man jq`  I don't know off-hand how to do what you want as I only use `--raw-output` to get single particular values from JSON within a bash script. But it may be somewhere to start.

Comment: @codlord I already use jq, but I haven't been able to get the desired output using jq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass simple strings into a `jq` filter using `--arg`, and JSON objects similarly using `--argjson`. Then use `{}` *object construction* to assemble the desired output:

```
profile_id=1
root_folder_path="/home/cas/plex-media/series"
add_options='
{
  "ignoreEpisodesWithFiles": false,
  "ignoreEpisodesWithoutFiles": false,
  "searchForMissingEpisodes": false
}'

jq --argjson p "$profile_id" --argjson a "$add_options" --arg r "$root_folder_path" '
  {title, rootFolderPath: $r, profileId: $p, tvdbId, titleSlug, images, seasons, addOptions: $a}
' input.json
```

Note that the value `$profile_id` needs to be passed as a JSON object in order to be treated as numeric.

See also:

- [jq Manual: Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)
- [jq Manual: Types and Values](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues)